# Multiple GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I would like to use a few GridViews in a single Layout. 
I don't know how to set an adapter, or if there is any other simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your xml layout, add as many gridView as u  want.
In your activity, get the reference of each gridview w.r.t their id and make seperate adapters for each gridview. Or pass diffrenet parametres to the same adapter for each gridView.

```
GridView grid1 = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid1);
GridView grid2 = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid2);

grid1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, arrayOfImagesSet1));
grid2.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, arrayOfImagesSet2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple way you can use the wizard to create a DataSource for each grideview. 
Change to design mode and start generating your DataSource.